# Using foreach instead of map and grep in perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
my @a_columns = map { s/^"|"$|\n|\r|\n\r|"//g; $_ } split /;/, $s_act_line;
```

above mentioned is my code. i am getting automatic warning while merging this code because of the usage of the map function.
please help me to convert this using for or foreach or any loop.

I have already tried couple of ways but nothing works for me.

please help me guys

[image]

Comment: What automatic warning are you getting? I can run this code just fine, provided I declare a variable called `$s_act_line`. It runs fine under `use strict; use warnings;` too (which you should be using anyway)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Sounds like a lint warning from their IDE.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I have attached the image of the warning.
I used List library then I got an exception List.pm is not available

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Is this copy-paste-programming without understanding the pasted code? A better question would be: how does this map work?

Comment: If you don't escape the dollar sign, this `$|` will be interpreted as [the predefined variable that handles autoflush](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH).

Answer (score 7):

The warning appears to follow [Perl::Critic](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic) (even though it seems to be issued by your IDE).

The variable `$_` in `map`, but also in `grep` and `foreach`, is an alias for the currently processed array element. So once it gets changed the *input* array gets changed!  This is usually unwanted, and can surely be considered a tricky practice in general, thus the warning.

But in this case the input for `map` is the list produced by `split`, used on your variable.  So code in `map`'s block cannot change your variables by changing `$_`.  Then it is safe to tell `Perl::Ciritic` to [ignore](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic#BENDING-THE-RULES) this statement

```
my @a_columns = 
    map { s/^"|"$|\n|\r|\n\r|"//g; $_ } split /;/, $s_act_line;  ## no critic
```

or for more than one statement

```
## no critic

... code that Perl::Critic should ignore

## use critic
```

If the warning is indeed produced by `Perl::Critic` (and not by IDE) this should stop it.

Better yet, the idiom used in `map`'s block is unneeded with Perl versions from 5.14, since we got the [non-destructive substitution](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta#Non-destructive-substitution). With it `s///r` *returns* the changed string, leaving the original unchanged.  So you can do

```
my @a_columns = map { s/^"|"$|\n|\r|\n\r|"//gr } split /;/, $s_act_line;
```

which is also much cleaner and safer.  Now `Perl::Critic` should not flag this.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're modifying `$_` in the `map`, which means you're modifying the values passed to `map`. That can lead to surprises. Switching to `for` wouldn't help.

It's actually harmless in this case since `split` returns temporary values, but the following are "clean" alternatives:

```perl
my @a_columns =
   map { ( my $tmp = $_ ) =~ s/^"|"$|\n|\r|\n\r|"//g; $tmp }
      split /;/, $s_act_line;
```

```perl
use List::MoreUtils qw( apply );

my @a_columns =
   apply { s/^"|"$|\n|\r|\n\r|"//g; }
      split /;/, $s_act_line;
```

```perl
my @a_columns =
   map { s/^"|"$|\n|\r|\n\r|"//rg }
      split /;/, $s_act_line;
```

Comment: my @a_columns =
   map { ( my $tmp = $_ ) =~ s/^"|"$|\n|\r|\n\r|"//g; $tmp }
      split /;/, $s_act_line;
This actually worked fine for me .. Thank you for the support guys  
please forgive me for pasting the code directly, I am absolute beginner